# Argument Type List<dynamic> can't be assigned to List<String> while fetching data from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, casting

This is my data fetching file:

```
static Future<List<ServiceCardModel>> getServiceCardList(
      String storeUid) async {
    List<ServiceCardModel> servicelist = [];
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection('stores')
        .doc(storeUid)
        .collection('service_cards')
        .get();

    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      String name = doc.data()['name'] ?? '';
      String price = doc.data()['price'] ?? '';
      List<String> valid = doc.data()['valid'] ?? '';
      List<String> invalid = doc.data()['invalid'] ?? '';

      ServiceCardModel serviceCardModel = ServiceCardModel(
          name: name, price: price, valid: valid, invalid: invalid);

      servicelist.add(serviceCardModel);
    }

    return servicelist;
  }
```

This is *my data model*:

```
class ServiceCardModel {
  String name;
  String price;
  List<String> valid;
  List<String> invalid;

  ServiceCardModel(
      {required this.name,
      required this.price,
      required this.valid,
      required this.invalid});
}
```

This is my UI part:

```
FutureBuilder<List<ServiceCardModel>>(
                  future: serviceCardList,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return CarouselSlider(
                          options: CarouselOptions(
                            height: 400,
                            autoPlay: true,
                            enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          ),
                          items: snapshot.data!.map((e) {
                            return Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                color: Color(0xFFE2FF6D),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    spreadRadius: 2,
                                    blurRadius: 5,
                                    offset: Offset(0,
                                        3), // changes the position of the shadow
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          e.name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: SizedBox(
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Card(
                                            elevation: 10,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                            ),
                                            child: Container(
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  'Rs.${e.price}',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 26),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: SizedBox(
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                    ListView.builder(
                                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                        itemCount: e.valid.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          return Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Icon(
                                                Icons.check_circle,
                                                color: Colors.green,
                                                size: 18,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 5,
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  e.valid[index],
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                ),
                                                flex: 7,
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: SizedBox(
                                                  width: 1,
                                                ),
                                                flex: 1,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          );
                                        }),
                                    ListView.builder(
                                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                        itemCount: e.invalid.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          return Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Icon(
                                                Icons.cancel,
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                size: 18,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 5,
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  e.invalid[index],
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                ),
                                                flex: 7,
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: SizedBox(
                                                  width: 1,
                                                ),
                                                flex: 1,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          );
                                        }),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList());
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      //print('error hai bsdk');
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                )
```

And Valid and Invalid are the two lists.
I am unable to cast them to dynamic. Please, how can I do that and use their data?
As the error is.

I looked for similar, but they said casting was an option, but how can I use casting here if possible? The rest, is there another solution to this?

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

Comment: It is still somewhat incomprehensible. Are you using [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)?

Comment: The three [backticks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick#Noun) should be on a ***separate line***. Otherwise the first line is hidden. There were three instances of that here.

Answer (score 0):

```
String storeUid) async {
    List<ServiceCardModel> servicelist = [];
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection('stores')
        .doc(storeUid)
        .collection('service_cards')
        .get();

    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      String name = doc.data()['name'] ?? '';
      String price = doc.data()['price'] ?? '';
      List<String> valid = (doc.data()['valid'] is List) ? (doc.data()['valid'].map((e)=> e.toString()).toList()) : [];
      List<String> invalid = (doc.data()['invalid'] is List) ? (doc.data()['invalid'].map((e) => e.toString()).toList()) : [];

      ServiceCardModel serviceCardModel = ServiceCardModel(
          name: name, price: price, valid: valid, invalid: invalid);

      servicelist.add(serviceCardModel);
    }

    return servicelist;
  }
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change? Why did you change it? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76499863/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: The first line of the data fetching file was hidden. You may want to update your answer. (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now)